# What is the importance of Default exports in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

In http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html#default-exports-one-per-module, it's stated about **default exports** that:

> Modules that only export single values are very popular in the Node.js
>   community. But they are also common in frontend development where you
>   often have constructors/classes for models, with one model per module.
>   An ECMAScript 6 module can pick a default export, the most important
>   exported value. **Default exports are especially easy to import.**

**My Question:** Is `default export` just a lazy coder style to make the import easy ? or does it have other importance. I don't come from NodeJS community, Im a pythoner, so **trying to understand the need for exporting a default method to import it in a easy way**.

**EDITED:**

Example:

**With export default**

```
//------ MyClass.js ------
export default class { ... };

//------ main2.js ------
import MyClass from 'MyClass';
```

Without export default

```
//------ MyClass.js ------
export App class { ... };

//------ main2.js ------
import {App} from 'MyClass';
```

In the above example, what I see is just avoiding flower brackets in export default ? Is there is anything beyond that  ?

Comment: As it says: they're simply easy to import as `import Foo from 'bar'`. Anything else needs more verbose import syntax and more awareness of what exactly the module is exporting…

Comment: yes, but if I dont use export default, I will import with `import {Foo} from 'bar'`, so whats so easy to import about it ?

Comment: The need for `{}`, and the need to use exactly the name `Foo` as it's exported from the module. With `import Foo from ...` the name in the module itself doesn't need to be `Foo`, it just needs to be the `default`.

Comment: (And no, we're really not talking about something that becomes stupendously "hard" without `default`…)

Comment: check this article: https://danmartensen.svbtle.com/build-better-apps-with-es6-modules#es6-modules_1 it will explain everything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can and will make a difference when you consider tree-shaking and larger, more complex modules. Let's say you made a giant util library:

```
export function filterObjects(array, predicate) {
   // code
}

export function massiveExpensiveFunction(args) {
   // lots of code
}

...a lot more code

export default {
   massiveExpensiveFunction,
   filterObjects
}
```

You now have the option of:

```
import Util from './Util';
```

Which will load all of the code, including your massiveExpensiveFunction, or:

```
import { filterObjects } from './Util';
```

Which given the right module building system that supports tree-shaking, will only import the used portions of the code. This could reduce the overall build size by eliminating unused/unnecessary code.

Comment: This looks like a perfect use-case and importance of **export default** to me.  Thanks a lot .

Comment: There are tools that can decide what is to be included in the final package even if you import everything. You could still import using `import {* as Util}` so I don't think this is the most important use case.

Comment: @Sulthan What would you say is the most important use case then? It definitely seems like the real benefit of providing `export` and `export default` (outside of slightly less typing) is allowing developers to selectively import portions of libraries. I know there are build tools that will provide dead-code elimination, but this seems like the most obvious way for developers to intentionally exclude unused code.

Answer (score 2):

```
export Foo ...;
```

When importing this it requires you to:

1. Use the `{}` syntax, and
2. use the exact name `Foo`:

```
import {Foo} from ...;
```

If you wish to import it under a different name, it even requires:

```
import {Foo as Bar} from ...;
```

However, with a default export:

```
export default ...;
```

1. You can skip the `{}` (yeah, just two characters…), and
2. you can import it directly under any name you wish:

```
import Bar from ...;
```

It's not a *ginormous* difference, but it can make code just that little bit simpler and thereby more readable if there's only a single importable in a module anyway, which is typical in Javascript.

Comment: True, but im wondering why there should be default in the first place, `python`(im a pythoner) never had that . So wondering whats makes importing default makes it important. Because when you want something you will import with name anyways ? If I should think that i can name the import any name i want when i use default, I can stil do that with `import foo as bar from 'something';` Wondering what could be the reason ES6 introduced it ?

Comment: It is literally just a tiny helper that allows you to do `import ArbitraryName` instead of `import {Foo as ArbitraryName}`. Nothing more, nothing less. Since often there only is one thing in a module, it makes sense to make that default case (pardon the pun) dead simple to import. In Python the one-module-one-importable is used less often, so makes less sense there.

Comment: True .. `Since often there only is one thing in a module, it makes sense to make that default case (pardon the pun) dead simple to import.` makes perfect sense. This is what i've been searching for. :) Please update this in your answer. I will mark it as answer :) Thanks

Comment: haha true!..  Just realised it. didn't realise that its a common practise until you stressed it again.

Answer (score 1):

Well it does not have anything to do with react in particular, but it's much easier and simple to only have to do :

```
import Foo from 'bar'
```

Instead of :

```
import { Foo } from 'bar'
```

When you are only exporting one thing from the `bar` module.

Honestly do whatever feels right for you, but its pretty much a standard in the javascript community and widely used

as an example : airbnb's eslint spec : https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#modules--prefer-default-export

Comment: but, when I need both default and named exports I have to do this anyways. `import React, { Component } from 'react'`. So I think my comfort is gone now :( .  wondering why not can I add the default export in brakets when I'm importing multiple

Comment: Because React is the default export, you can't add it as a normal export inside { }.

Comment: @rrmerugu You don't have to do that. You can still use `React.Component` instead.

Comment: @Sulthan yeah i know, but in one of the `thenewboston.com` videos, its just shown that way, so putting is as an example.  But now that I understood the export default from @Rob 's answer, I now understand that :) . Thanks for the tip though